# Parsing JSON and checking whether key exists

Tags: ios, json

Im parsing JSON from a server, however I have the problem that if the user does not have a credit card attached to an account it returns this:

[image]

But when they do have a credit card attached it returns this:

[image]

Ive tried the following code to determine whether `card_first_name` is not nil, but it crashes because obviously `card_first_name` does not exist yet. How would I handle this situation? Please see my current code below:

```
if (dict[@"message"][@"card_details"] !=[NSNull null]) {
    if (dict[@"message"][@"card_details"][@"card_first_name"]!=nil)       /*crashes here */ {
        NSLog(@"%@",dict[@"message"][@"card_details"][@"card_first_name"]);

    }
    if (dict[@"message"][@"card_details"][@"card_last_name"]!=[NSNull null]) {
        NSLog(@"%@",dict[@"message"][@"card_details"][@"card_last_name"]);

    }
    if (dict[@"message"][@"card_details"][@"card_number"]!=[NSNull null]) {
        NSLog(@"%@",dict[@"message"][@"card_details"][@"card_number"]);

    }

    if (dict[@"message"][@"card_details"][@"card_type"]!=[NSNull null]) {
        NSLog(@"%@",dict[@"message"][@"card_details"][@"card_type"]);

    }
    if (dict[@"message"][@"card_details"][@"expiry"]!=[NSNull null]) {
        NSLog(@"%@",dict[@"message"][@"card_details"][@"expiry"]);

    }
    if (dict[@"message"][@"card_details"][@"payment_ref"]!=[NSNull null]) {
        NSLog(@"%@",dict[@"message"][@"card_details"][@"payment_ref"]);


    }
}
```

Thanks in advance, and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you are checking for card_details to not be nil which it isn't if you are reaching the first name check. You will need to determine if there is a key count or card_details is empty not null.

Comment: @RLS checking for the key count worked like a charm

Comment: @RLS would you like to post your solutions as an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine if there is a key count for card details.

```
NSUInteger keyCount = [dictionary count];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just verify first if key exists then check if has value:

```
       if(dict["message"]key key)
```

do this starting from the first possible (expected) key, in your case "message", then for all subseqwent (expected keys, subkeys).

Comment: Verify first if dict has key, do for other key key. Do not check if it is null or not before you don't verify if key exists.

Comment: `if (dict[@"message"][@"card_details"][@"card_first_name"])` still crashing